# Spring Opentracing Jaeger header forwarding with Istio

Tags: spring, istio, jaeger, opentracing

I'm running Spring with the *opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter* in Istio with jaeger, even when I enable b3-propagation and w3c-propagation, jaeger is breaking the spans.
Is there a way to validate what the sidecar receives? I tried using WebClient and RestTemplate, same result with both. I don't want to forward the header manually in the controller.

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes and Istio did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: It's Openshift 4.7 baremetal, Istio 1.11.